# Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: mysql

```
$sql_top = mysql_query ( "SELECT `players`.`name`, `players`.`age` FROM `players` ORDER BY `age` DESC LIMIT 10" ) ;
if ( ! mysql_num_rows ( $sql_top ) ) {
    echo 'Игроков не найдено';
}
else {
    echo'<table class="nomb table-style01" style="float: right; width: 100%;">';
    echo'<tr class="bg">
    <td><b>№</b></td>
    <td><b>Имя</b></td>
    <td><b>Состояние</b></td>
    </tr>';
    $c = 0;
```

Comment: Ждем @eicto с красиво отформатированным комментарием об устарелости функции

Comment: [depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

[исходник шаблона](http://paste.debian.net/41229/)

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в запросе к базе данных. Попробуйте выполнить запрос не в PHP, увидите в чем ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Результат запроса `false`; Значит какая-то ошибка. Выведите `mysql_error`

> `For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
> resultset, mysql_query() returns a
> resource on success, or FALSE on
> error.`